# What default fonts Google Chrome uses in Windows 10 (English language)?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

In

```
chrome://settings/fonts
```

What are default Standard, Serif, Sans Serif and Fixed-Width font?

This is needed for people who are not using Windows, but would like the same (or similar) setup if possible.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. Please delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997445/what-default-fonts-chrome-os-uses-in-2017

Comment: it's not the same question, this one is for Windows 10, and that one is for Chrome OS (different operating system). It is needed for people who want to test some fonts if they don't use that operating system.

Comment: you will never have that guarantee unless you can match 'exact font versions*. If you can't, you have nothing you can truly rely on

Comment: that's true, although Arial for example (if the version is from the last 10 years), probably look almost identical for English language text. Actually, I checked Microsoft website and perhaps subpixel rendering looks different https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1705 but character spacing almost identical between versions

Comment: What about Ubuntu? There is no Consolas in the list.

Answer (score 2):

- Standart: Times New Roman
- Serif: Times New Roman
- Sans Serif: Arial
- Fixed-Width: Consolas

Source: my own google-chrome